# Extjs 4.1.1 How to align the toolbar items one below the others?

Tags: extjs4.1

```
I am using Extjs 4.1.1
```

I have panel on which I have added toolbar at bottom side.
This toolbar has 3 items, I want to aling first item in first row, and rest two items in next row, i.e. one below others.

as shown in the image, I want to align the items as shown above to the Red Rectangle.
My code is as given below.

Please suggest How can I do that?

my code is like this

```
 dockedItems: [ 
                     {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            height:60,
            items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'tbtext',
                        id:'costId',
                        text   : "Total Cost <br> $66,000",
                        height : 40
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button', 
                        autoAlign: 'bottom',
                        id: 'saveButton',
                        text: 'Add to BOM', 
                        handler: function() {
                            saveProduct();
                        } 
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button', 
                        autoAlign: 'bottom',
                        id: 'cancelButton',
                        text: 'Cancel', 
                        handler: function() {
                            cancel();
                        }
                    }
```

]
            }],

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be adding two bottom toolbars to the panel. Just like this:

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    border: false,
    style: {
        background: 'white'
    },
    items: [{
        text: 'Add to BoM',
        cls: 'add-to-bom-button'
    }, {
        text: 'Cancel',
        cls: 'cancel-button'
    }]
}, {
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    border: false,
    style: {
        background: 'white'
    },
    items: [costContainer]
}]
```

where **costContainer** is

```
var costContainer = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
border: false,
layout: 'vbox',
items: [{
    xtype: 'label',
    html: 'Total Cost',
    cls: 'total-cost-label'
}, {
    xtype: 'label',
    html: '$ 66,000',
    cls: 'price-label'
}]
});
```

I think this example looks like what you are looking for, just have to fix the css.
http://jsfiddle.net/alexrom7/LHK39/3/

Comment: Awesome help, Thanks a lot , I was expecting same. 
My mistake was I have included two seperate dockItems for toolbar, and so the styling got disturbed. 
Once again thanks